# After using quoteInto Am I safe from SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-injection

Hello I am using `quoteInto` in my query like below

```
 $select->from('users')
 ->where($adapter->quoteInto('eu.username LIKE ?',"%".$param['name']."%"));
```

When I pass any thing like 'or -1=-1' or any think like

```
 ' or 1=1--
 ' or 1--
 ' or 1
 \" or '1'
 ' or 1=1--
 ' OR ''='
 ' or 'a'='a
  ') or ('a'='a
'; exec master..xp_cmdshell 'ping 10.10.1.2'--
 ';
```

When I echo my query, all this stuff is put in `LIKE` clause of my query. I just want to ask that after quoting my query is safe from sql injection?

Comment: FYI, `->where('eu.username LIKE ?', "%".$params['name']."%");` will do exactly the same thing but with less code.

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks dude but have multiple conditions. So have to use multiple orwhere or where. So that is too large than the code I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are safe from SQL injections by using the db adapter quote functions.

When you use `quoteInto` Zend will call [Zend_Db_Adapter::quote](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote) method to escape the value string.

> From Zend Docs:
>   The quote() method accepts a single argument, a scalar string value.
>   It returns the value with special characters escaped in a manner
>   appropriate for the RDBMS you are using, and surrounded by string
>   value delimiters.

To make your application safer you should also use `Zend_Form` with elements utilizing available [Zend Filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.filters) and [Zend Validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators). Validation of elements will catch the problem and avoid junk database calls and filters will sanitize your data!